# Listen on port that is already listed as source port of an established connection?

Tags: networking

If a connection is in an ESTABLISHED state with local address 127.0.0.1:45000, would it be possible for a local process to bind and listen on the same port 45000 or would that port be considered already in use and block the bind request?

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/q/14388706/632951

Answer (score 2):

The `bind` will fail with `errno` set to `EINVAL`. If you really want to do it, you'd have to `tcpdump` or other means of packet capture to see what's going on. `strace` on the process would also be an option, along with other kernel diagnostics.

Answer (score 2):

The full story is "it depends on what you mean."  If you would like to listen on the exact same IP and port as an existing program that you have no control over, then as others have indicated, you may be out of luck.  If however, you:

- Can listen on a different IP address, or
- Have some control over the original application

then you might be interested in the rest of this post.

### Same Port, Different Internet Protocol (IP) Address

When a program uses the [bind(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/bind.2.html) system call to assign an address to a socket, that adddress (in the case of an AF_INET socket) specifies both the port and the IP address.  Two addresses with the same port but different IP addresses are thus different and can be assigned to separately without conflict.  For example, using [socat](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/doc/socat.html) I can bind to port 9000 on the IP address for my loopback interface in one shell:

```
 socat TCP4-LISTEN:9000,bind=127.0.0.1 STDOUT
```

and bind to the same port but on my external IP address in another:

```
socat TCP4-LISTEN:9000,bind=10.0.2.15 STDOUT
```

Both processes can accept connections that come in on the IP address & port they are listening on.  Note, however, that if someone is listening on the wildcar address 0.0.0.0, then you cannot bind to a more specific address since the first process is bound to every IP on the system.

### Same Port, Same IP

By default, two processes cannot bind two different file descriptors the same address.  On Linux, attempting to do so will result in EADDRINUSE being returned from `bind(2)`:

```
socat TCP4-LISTEN:9000,bind=127.0.0.1 STDOUT
2014/11/07 00:10:13 socat[21202] E bind(3, {AF=2 127.0.0.1:9000}, 16): Address already in use
```

Given your question and follow up, I am guessing you don't have much control over the program currently using your desired port.  If you did however, it is possible for one process to have an established connection on a port + ipaddress while another is listening on the same address.  For instance, many server applications do the following:

- Have a main process bind(), listen(), and accept() a connection
- Fork a new process to handle the accepted connection, with the main process going back to try to accept() any new incoming connections.

In this case, you would see a child process with an ESTABLISHED connection on the port and the parent process with a LISTENing socket on the same port.

In very recent Linux kernels, it is possible for two completely unrelated processes to both bind to the same address using the SO_REUSEPORT socket option.  If a processes sets the SO_REUSEPORT option on the socket, then other processes with the same effective UID of the first process can also set the SO_REUSEPORT option and bind to the same address.

Unfortunately, my version of `socat` seems to have a bug that makes it hard to give an easy TCP example; however, I've provided a short and poorly written example program below.  If you run that program as the same user in two different shells, both will bind() without an issue:

```
State    Recv-Q Send-Q  Local Address:Port  Peer Address:Port
LISTEN   0      128     127.0.0.1:9000        *:*     users:(("bind_tcp_reusep",pid=21254,fd=3))
LISTEN   0    128 127.0.0.1:9000           *:*      users:(("bind_tcp_reusep",pid=21253,fd=3))
```

The goal of this is to give people writing network servers a new tool to create applications that can handle a large number of concurrent connections.

The following LWN article has a good overview of the use case for this option:

http://lwn.net/Articles/542629/

### Watching traffic on an established connection

As robbat2 mentioned, if you want to spy on existing traffic `tcpdump` is the best bet.

### Example SO_REUSEPORT program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netinet/tcp.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>


int main() {
  struct sockaddr_in bind_addr;
  struct sockaddr peer_addr;
  int optval = 1;
  int tcp_socket;
  int err;
  int addr_len = sizeof(struct sockaddr);

  memset(&bind_addr, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
  memset(&peer_addr, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr));
  bind_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  bind_addr.sin_port = htons(9000);

  if (inet_pton(AF_INET, "127.0.0.1", &(bind_addr.sin_addr)) != 1) {
    perror("inet_pton");
    exit(1);
  }

  tcp_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  setsockopt(tcp_socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEPORT, &optval, sizeof(optval));
  err = bind(tcp_socket, (const struct sockaddr *)&bind_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr));

  if (err != 0) {
    perror("bind failed");
    exit(1);
  }

  err = listen(tcp_socket, 256);
  if (err != 0) {
    perror("listen failed");
    exit(1);
  }
  accept(tcp_socket, &peer_addr, &addr_len);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just tried this on my own by starting up a local Tomcat server and tweaking the configuration to bind to a port that was already listed as the source address of an ESTABLISHED connection. It allowed the server to bind to the port in a LISTEN state while there was another ESTABLISHED connection already using that port as the local address.